# How do you enlarge the search icon on an NSSearchField?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm making a search field with a larger height than the default. Although its text size can be increased to the proper size, the icon stays the same size:

[image: search bar with tiny search icon in the top left corner]

I tried to fix this by overriding `NSSearchField`'s `rectForSearchButton(whenCentered:)`'s default rectangle. However, not only did it not increase the size of the button, but it also duplicated the button image.

```
override func rectForSearchButton(whenCentered isCentered: Bool) -> NSRect {
    return NSRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30)
}
```

[image: search field where the buttons are overlapping]

I then tried commenting out the above and subclassing `NSSearchFieldCell`, which had a similar result.

```
override func searchButtonRect(forBounds rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
    return NSRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30)
}
```

[image: search field still with two icons]

How can I properly center and enlarge this icon? I want it to fill up the whole space and be centered, or at least look like a normal search field.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change button image scaling. Assuming your custom class is instantiated from Storyboard/XIB and the height is modified via constraint, it could be like below:

[image: NSSearchField button image]

```
class CustomSearchFiled: NSSearchField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        if let cell = self.cell as? NSSearchFieldCell {
            cell.searchButtonCell?.imageScaling = .scaleProportionallyUpOrDown
        }
    }
    ...
```